# Portable way to switch the foreground application focus?

Tags: python, focus, cross-platform

I am writing some tests in Python to try to do some black box testing on an application that runs on both Windows and OS X. My problem is that some behavior of this application expects an external tool to get launched to handle some task and then afterwards gets focus back, at which point it knows to update itself.

So I need a way to tell the OS in either a Windows or OS X environment "Make application X the focused application." How do I do this?

Comment: I made your requested edit.